# how to write xpath to select a value with 2 or more conditions

Tags: xml, xpath

Below is the sample xml :

I need to select value of the message tag i.e. "xpath statement result" with condition on "Condition_1 = Extract" and "Condition_2 = AuthorizationViaV1".

```
<Row1>
    <uniquekey>11110011</uniquekey>
    <TrackingID>level123</TrackingID>
    <timestamp>2015-06-12T13:28:44.959+05:30</timestamp>
    <acquiretime>500</acquiretime>
    <Condition_1>Login</Condition_1>
    <Condition_2>AuthorizationViaV1</Condition_2>
    <message>xpath statement result</message>
    <payload>abcdefghi</payload>
</Row1>
```

Comment: Okay, this is very basic and straight-forward. Have you tried solving it yourself? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `and` boolean operator in the condition:

```
Row1[Condition_1 = 'Extract' and Condition_2 = 'AuthorizationViaV1']/message
```

or you can chain the conditions:

```
Row1[Condition_1 = 'Extract'][Condition_2 = 'AuthorizationViaV1']/message
```